# ¿Cómo puedo convertir de un tipo a otro c#?

Tags: c#, conversión-de-tipos, tipos

Guia definitiva de conversión de tipos en [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)

- Convertir `String` a `Integer`
- Convertir `Integer` a `String`
- Convertir `char` a `String`
- Convertir `String` a `char`
- Convertir `String` a `Double`
- Convertir `Double` a `String`
- Convertir `String` a `Float`
- Convertir `Float` a `String`
- Convertir `String` a `bool`
- Convertir `bool` a `String`
- Convertir `Byte[]` a `String`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## String a Integer

```
int entero = Int32.Parse(cadena);
// o
Int32.TryParse(cadena, out entero);
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
int cantidad = Int32.Parse("60");

int importe;
if(Int32.TryParse("60", out importe)){
     Console.WriteLine(importe);
}
```

## Integer a String

```
String cadena = entero.ToString();
String cadena = string.Format("{0}", entero);
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
String cadena = 60.ToString();
String cadena = string.Format("{0}", 60);
```

## char a String

```
String cadena = caracter.ToString();
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
String codigo = 'a'.ToString();

char caracter = '0';
String clave =  caracter.ToString();
```

## String a char

```
char caracter = cadena[0]; //Solo primer caracter
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
string queryString = "a=1?c=2"
char evento = queryString[0];

string mensaje = "404";
char detalle = mensaje[2]; //para obtener 4
```

## String a Double

```
Double doble = Convert.ToDouble(cadena);
// o    
Double doble = double.Parse(cadena, cultura);
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
Double doble = Convert.ToDouble("50.5");

// o    
Double doble = double.Parse("50.5", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Nota: [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

## Double a String

```
String cadena = doble.ToString();
// o
String cadena = doble.ToString("0.000000"); //Usando mascara
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
String cadena = 55.5.ToString();
// o
String cadena = 55.5.ToString("0.000000"); //Usando mascara
```

## String a Float

```
float flotante = float.Parse(cadena, cultura);
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
float.Parse("90.852", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Nota: [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

## Float a String

```
String cadena = flotante.toString()
// o 
String cadena = flotante.toString("0.000");
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
String cadena = 55.5f.toString()
// o 
float kilogramos = 90.5f;
String kiloStr= kilogramos.toString("0.000");
```

## String a bool

```
bool boleano = Convert.ToBoolean("true");    
// o
bool boleano = cadena == "1";
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
bool boleano = Convert.ToBoolean("false");    
// o
bool boleano = resultado == "1";
```

## bool a String

```
String cadena = boleano.ToString();
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
String resultado = true.ToString();
// o 
bool aplicar = true;
String resultado = aplicar.ToString();
```

## Arreglo de Bytes a String

```
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(arregloBytes);
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
byte[] arreglo = new byte[] { 1,2,3};
Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(arreglo));
```

**Notas generales:**

¿[Confundido con el uso de String y de string](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-string-y-string/)?