# Conversión de un tipo de datos string a double. C#

Tags: c#, conversión-de-tipos

Cómo convertir un objeto string a double sin perder precision, por ejemplo 12.9 (string) a double.

Comment: Al ver los comentarios debajo de las respuestas, parece que tu pregunta tiene mas que ver con un problema en particular que estás teniendo. De ser el caso, por favor incluye un [mcve] para entender el problema.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Guia definitiva de conversión de tipos en c#](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1738/guia-definitiva-de-conversi%c3%b3n-de-tipos-en-c)

Answer (score 6):

Buenas.
Para convertir un numero desde string a double se usa:

```
Convert.ToDouble(value);
```

Esto está documentado en [Convert to double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k(v=vs.110).aspx).
Cuando la conversión pierda precisión, se lanzará una excepción.

También es importante mencionar que esta función hace una llamada a [`Double.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447(v=vs.110).aspx) con el formato de la cultura en la que el programa esta ejecutándose, esto afecta en la forma en la que se interpreta el valor con referencia a elementos como el . (punto) o la , (coma). Para formatear la entrada sin considerar la configuracion cultural local se usa:

```
double.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Se pueden ver ejemplos del uso de los distintos formatos en [IFormatProvider Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider(v=vs.110).aspx)

Cuando necesites mas precisión, puedes usar el tipo [Decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx).
Este tiene un rango de (-7.9 x 1028 hasta 7.9 x 1028) / (100 hasta 28)

Comment: El problema es que la conversión que realizo queda a 129 (usando el ejemplo que coloqué en la pregunta), y si, uso Convert.ToDouble(value); para ello.

Comment: Probablemente tenga que ver con el formato local. Prueba algo como esto ```double.Parse("3.5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)```

Comment: Si, yo también probé en otra pc y si funciona, cuando llegue a casa daré más información si Dios lo permite.

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó usar CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
string convertirvalor ="12.9";
double valorconvertido = double.Parse(convertirvalor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas usar el método `Convert.ToDouble` que lo puedes usar de la siguiente manera

```
Convert.ToDouble(string);
```

te dejo la [documentacion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) de Microsoft por si te sirve consultarla.

Comment: El problema es que la conversión que realizo queda a 129 (usando el ejemplo que coloqué en la pregunta), y si, uso Convert.ToDouble(value); para ello.

Comment: ¿Podrías darnos más información?

Comment: Realicé el ejemplo en [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PioyZB) y parece que funciona todo bien

Comment: Si, yo también probé en otra pc y si funciona, cuando llegue a casa daré más información si Dios lo permite.

Comment: Añade la parte de código para que te podamos apoyar.

Comment: Tu configuración regional podría estar causándote problemas, de todos modos puedes probar esto:

Double mi_double = double.Parse(my_string, NumberStyles.AllowThousands| NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint , new CultureInfo("es-ES"));

Puedes verificar el resto de los parámetros Allow en [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo resolví usando `string.replace('.',',')`.

¿Se entiende?

Remplazar el separador decimal de punto por la coma y luego convertir a double.

```
string Peso;
double peso;
Peso = Peso.Replace('.',',');
peso = double.Parse(Peso);
```